# Finding a Div or placeholder in a repeater control, and adding controls to it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having trouble with a certain scenario. I have a repeater control, within I have a placeholder (and for the sake of testing, I've placed a div and tried that as well). I would like to, in my code behind page, find that placeholder or div, and put controls in it (for now, 3 textboxes and 2 buttons)

I have no issue with adding controls to a placeholder, I understand how that works, what I can't get here, is how to find this dynamic control here.

Here is some code snippets to help illustrate what I'm trying to do.

(the asp)

```
        <asp:Repeater id="rptSpecialNotes" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpSpecialNotesRepeater" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhSpecialNotesRepeater" runat="server">
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <p><%# eval("subject") %></p>
            <div id="specialNotes" runat="server"></div>
            <asp:imagebutton runat="server" AlternateText="add Motion" ImageUrl="images/controls/Exclaim.png" width="40" height="40"></asp:imagebutton>
            <asp:imagebutton runat="server" AlternateText="add document" ImageUrl="images/controls/Documents.png" width="40" height="40"></asp:imagebutton>
            <asp:imagebutton runat="server" AlternateText="move up" ImageUrl="images/controls/Arrow-Up.png" width="40" height="40" CommandName="moveUp" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex & "," &  eval("ItemID") %>'></asp:imagebutton>
            <asp:imagebutton runat="server" AlternateText="move down" ImageUrl="images/controls/Arrow-Down.png" width="40" height="40" CommandName="moveDown" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex & "," &  eval("ItemID") %>'></asp:imagebutton>
            <asp:imagebutton runat="server" AlternateText="delete" ImageUrl="images/controls/Delete.png" width="40" height="40" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex & "," &  eval("ItemID") %>'></asp:imagebutton>
            <asp:imagebutton runat="server" AlternateText="edit" ImageUrl="images/controls/Globe.png" width="40" height="40" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex & "," &  eval("ItemID") %>'></asp:imagebutton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

The image button edit, hits the rptSpecialNotes_Item command, which calls a method (edit special notes) which looks something like this

```
    Dim commandArguments() As String = Split(e.CommandArgument, ",")
    Dim divId As String = commandArguments(0)
    Dim itemId As String = commandArguments(1)



    'determine action based on command name
    If e.CommandName = "edit" Then
        Call editSpecialNotes(itemId,divId)
    End If
```

and edit special notes is to place things in the given divID. For the sake of getting this to work, I've given divID a static value that I know exists (rptSpecialNotes_plhSpecialNotesRepeater_1) or something similar to that extent. However, I always end up with a null object reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) to get the nested control in the `rptSpecialNotes_Item` event handler - this will *return* the control:

```
sender.FindControl("specialNotes")
```

It will return a `Control` type, so a cast is needed to the right type if you want to use the specific properties and methods of that type.

Comment: so if I do something like this?
Dim plh As PlaceHolder = Me.Page.FindControl("rptSpecialNotes_udpSpecialNotesRepeater_0") I should find the control. However That still propagates the error.

Comment: Ah you know, the findcontrol doesn't error out, however I can't add any controls to it afterwards. 
something like: plh.controls.add(lbl)
that errors out

Comment: @Lenigod - That's something else. Do you have an exception and stack trace?

Comment: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

The exception isn't long, but long enough that I can't paste the whole thing in, if you'll continue helping, I can take a screenshot and put it up on imgur, if that helps you help me more! :D

Comment: @Lenigod - Possibly time for a new question... It is getting late for me.

Comment: Allright, thank you. At the very least, you've help me properly identify the root cause of my error here. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe this helps:

```
<asp:imagebutton runat="server" AlternateText="edit" ImageUrl="images/controls/Globe.png" width="40" height="40" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ClientID & "," &  eval("ItemID") %>'></asp:imagebutton>
```

also, for FindControl method, in ItemDataBound event;

```
Dim plh As PlaceHolder = e.Item.FindControl("YOURCONTROLID")
```

Comment: This finds the control properly, but I'm still yet unable to add controls to the placeholder itself. As suggested above, this is a different question entirely. You are correct, but the question I asked is wrong I guess.

Comment: When you find the PlaceHolder, Panel and ..., you can add any child control to them: `Dim lbl As New Label, lbl.Text = "SomeText", lbl.Attributes.Add("Key", "Value"), plh.Controls.Add(lbl)`. You can do the same for ant control you wish.

Answer (score 0):

In the rptSpecialNotes_Item command event handler:

```
Dim plh As PlaceHolder = CType(e.Item.FindControl("plhSpecialNotesRepeater"), PlaceHolder)

plh.Controls.Add(lbl)
```

Comment: This is somewhat correct. However, after defining plh as a placeholder, I'm still unable to add things to it. As suggested above, this is a different question entirely.